# React-Native - How to concat two strings inside JSX element

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Actually i am getting values from props, I need to concat those values and put in JSX text element. But i am trying to appending it is not working. Is there any way to make this happen. I don't want to create any other variable to concat.

Code :

```
 <Text style={{marginTop = 15}}>{this.props.userinfo.token+this.props.userInfo.loggedin}</Text>
```

Comment: Hi skyshine did you have any luck integrating a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can render them separately

```
 <Text style={{marginTop = 15}}>
   {this.props.userinfo.token}{this.props.userInfo.loggedin}
 </Text>
```

OR

```
 <Text style={{marginTop = 15}}>
   {`${this.props.userinfo.token}${this.props.userInfo.loggedin}`}
 </Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

userinfo !== userInfo

```
 <Text style={{marginTop: 15}}>
   {this.props.userInfo.token + this.props.userInfo.loggedin}
 </Text>
```

You might also just have to verify that the props are active before trying to render them.

```
 <Text style={{marginTop: 15}}>
   { this.props.userInfo.token && this.props.userInfo.loggedIn ? (
      this.props.userInfo.token + this.props.userInfo.loggedin
    ) : (
      ""
   )}
 </Text>
```

Comment: whatever code i have written that is working, i did one mistake,  it should be like this <Text style={{marginTop : 15}}>

Answer (score 0):

While the answers above are correct.

I just want to share that you can also do the following:

```
<Text style={{marginTop: 15}}>
  {this.props.userinfo.token.concat(this.props.userInfo.loggedin)}
</Text>
```

Just make sure that `this.props.userinfo` isn't `undefined` nor `null` and has `token` and `loggedin` property.

And also this:

```
<Text style={{marginTop: 15}}>
  {`${this.props.userinfo.token}${this.props.userInfo.loggedin}`}
</Text>
```